# Fix Error converting data type varchar to numeric. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to run the following stored procedure using pyodbc.

```
USE [CompanyMC]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[marketprice]    Script Date: 15/10/2019 23:02:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[marketprice](@marketvalue AS VARCHAR(30))
  AS
  BEGIN
  SELECT TRY_CAST (CompanyMarketCap AS numeric) from CompanyMC.dbo.Companies
  where CompanyName= @marketvalue
  END
```

Here's my python code

```
    # Call the procedure and pass rhe arguments as a list
    sql=f"""\
        EXEC {proc_name} @marketvalue=?;
        """
    parameters = (company_name)
    cursor.execute(sql, parameters)

    # get the result set and iterate over it to get the returned value
    result = cursor.fetchval()
```

I keep running into the error.

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to numeric. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Can't seem to figure out what am doing wrong any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why, why, WHY, is your parameter named marketvalue defined as varchar? Same goes for column CompanyMarketCap. Don't allow bad data into your database and don't rely on converting datatypes without reason.

Comment: And perhaps your parameter name is very misleading - you compare it to a column named CompanyName.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using pyodbc 4.0.27 and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that will reliably reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @Caleb Njiiri - please revisit my response.  Please ask yourself if `CompanyName= @marketvalue` is correct.  Please consider writing an [MCVE].  And, at a minimum, please update your post with the data that's failing: `select CompanyMarketCap from companyMC.dbo.Companies where CompanyName='THE-COMPANY-THAT-FAILS'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you've got a legal numeric string stored in your varchar (for example, *NOT* "xyz", and *NOT* NULL).  Then try [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric, CompanyMarketCap) FROM CompanyMC.dbo.Companies WHERE CompanyName= @marketvalue
```

If NULLS are possible, then add a [COALSCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to your statement.